# Error after copying one class from Netbeans to Eclipse, no error but this project can't run

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm getting

> Error: Main method not found in class jbdc1.Main, please define the main method as:
>   public static void main(String[] args)

but no error found in class.

```
package jbdc1;

import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class Main  {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        MSSQLConnect connect = new MSSQLConnect("ASUS\\SQLEXPRESS",1809, "sa", "123456", "data0");

        ResultSet result = connect.excuteQuery("Select * From Table_1");
        System.out.println(CountRow(result));

        result = connect.excuteQuery("Select * From Table_1 ");
        System.out.println(CountRow(result));
        connect.Close();

    }
    protected static int CountRow(ResultSet result) throws SQLException {
        int count=0;
        while (result.next()) {
            count++;
        }
        return count;
    }

}
```

Comment: does that even compile ? the main method is missing the starting `{`

Comment: oh no it has { bro
my syntax errors when typing.  sr

Comment: Refresh your project (project explorer, right-click, refresh) and try again.

Comment: thank all bro, it's runing
:))))